# Change style and colors based on value in field through VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and am trying to port some code I made in Swift. Thanks to some help I'm progressing pretty nice. One of the last pieces is conditional styles. What I would like to achieve is the following:

I have range with values. If third value is 'true' I want the font style in that line to be bold, with a grey background for the complete line. If it is 'false' I want the second value to be red and bold.

[image: styles]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    Sub test()

        Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 1 To LastRow

                If .Range("C" & i).Value = True Then
                    With .Range("A1:C" & i)
                        .Font.Bold = True
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                    End With
                Else
                    With .Range("B" & i)
                        .Font.Bold = True
                        .Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    End With
                End If

            Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. Is there a way to make this 'independent' of the name of the worksheet? So for the current worksheet?

Comment: It Is independent. It s referring to a specific worksheet usign the 'With statement' if the answer helps you up vote to helps others with the same question

Comment: I'll certainly do that. But... if I copy the first sheet (so the new sheet has another name), it doesn't work on the new sheet. Is it possible to let it work on the 'current' sheet?

Comment: You ccould use `ActiveSheet` but is not a good idea. it s better to with the worksheet name